# Select first item by default

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I'm binding ModernTab.Links to a LinkCollection and want the first Link to be selected by default. This works if I hardcode it:

```
<mui:ModernTab Layout="List" Links="{Binding Years}" SelectedSource="hard-coded-uri"/>
```

The LinkCollection wont be static so I set SelectedSource to a new Property "SelectedYear" from my ViewModel:

```
<mui:ModernTab Layout="List" Links="{Binding Years}" SelectedSource="{Binding SelectedYear}"/>
```

"SelectedYear" is the first link in the LinkCollection "Years":

```
SelectedYear = Years.First();
```

I can verify that "SelectedYear" is the first link and I would have bet 100€ that this would work .. but it doesn't. No year is selected. I've defined the property SelectedYear like this:

```
    private Link _selectedYear { get; set; }
    public Link SelectedYear
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedYear;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedYear = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedYear");
        }
    }
```

Where is the flaw? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I suppose SelectedYear must to have other type, string or Uri maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

SelectedSource="{Binding SelectedYear.Source}"

in your xaml.

Answer (score 0):

In your XAML, set Listview's SelectedIndex property to zero.

That will be your default list item.

Comment: ModernTab seems not to have the property SelectedIndex :o(